# Handling HTTP status codes

Tags: api, http, dart

I'd like to get you'r advice on this one.
Suppose I want to handle the errors/status codes I get from POST or GET methods in http protocol, I tried to implement something like this:

```
class Login extends IRequest<Map<String, dynamic>> {
  Login(var email, var password) {
    var data = {'email': email, 'password': password};
    var url = API_PREFIX + LOGIN_ENDPOINT;
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var headers = {
      'Content-type': CONTENT_TYPE,
    };
  }

  Future<IResponse> login(var mail, var password) async {
    final response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case OK:
      case ACCEPTED:
        final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
        String key = responseJson['login_key'];
        String experial = responseJson['experial'];
        var token = LoginToken(key, experial);
        return token;
      case NOT_FOUND:
        return ErrorResponse(response.statusCode.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I'm doing the request in an async way, and then check for the response code, but there are many cases to choose from , starting from 200 up to 500, which makes the code very messy and ugly,
Is there any easy way to work around this?
I have though about try / catch, but is it usable in this situation? (I know try catch are for exceptions, and here I just want the status code of the result...)

Answer (score 0):

If you will take a look at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) you can see, that codes are divided into groups. 1xx means informational response, 2xx success and others. 
With switch statement you can check, to which group received code belongs and continue or throw an error.

Other option is to add interceptors, and check response codes there.